# post increment,pre increment and operator precedence

Tags: c, operators, post-increment

the answer is coming out to be 45.I cant understand how this thing is working.

```
main()
{
    int a =10;
    int i =  a++ + ++a + a++ + ++a;
    printf("%d , %d ", i,a);

}
```

Comment: Lot many answers already, please do a little search

Answer (score 3):

Actually the output is an `undefined behavior` which is fine.

From the C99 standard are 6.5 Expressions, §2

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value
>   to be stored.
>
> The order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified. If an attempt
>   is made to modify the result of an assignment operator or to access it
>   after the next sequence point, the behavior is undefined.